# Why does Access 2016 reject the syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want to create a table with selected columns from an existing larger table  The syntax below is what is recommended but ACCESS throws an error msg. What gives?

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM existing_table_name
    WHERE ....;
```

Comment: Try using `select into`.

Answer (score 1):

Every brand of SQL database can choose how complete its implementation of the SQL language is. MS Access in particular fails to support a lot of language features that are common in other brands of database.

You just have to verify the syntax you want to use is supported. You can do this by referring to the syntax documentation, for example: [CREATE TABLE Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql). The syntax and description makes no mention of `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`

But [SELECT.INTO Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql) shows that you can use the `SELECT ... INTO newtable FROM ...` form. The documentation says this will create *newtable* in the process.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access doesn't have a "create table as select syntax". Instead, you can use the "select into" syntax:

```sql
SELECT column1, column2
INTO   new_table_name
FROM   existing_table_name
WHERE  ...
```